# fast way to compare two vector containing strings

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I have a vector of strings I that pass to my function and I need to compare it with some pre-defined values. What is the fastest way to do this?

The following code snippet shows what I need to do (This is how I am doing it, but what is the fastest way of doing this):

```
bool compare(vector<string> input1,vector<string> input2)
{
   if(input1.size() != input2.size()
   {
      return false;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<input1.siz();i++)
   {
       if(input1[i] != input2[i])
       {
            return false;
       }
   }
   return true; 

}
int compare(vector<string> inputData)
{
     if (compare(inputData,{"Apple","Orange","three"}))
     {
          return 129;
     }
     if (compare(inputData,{"A","B","CCC"}))
     {
          return 189;
     }
     if (compare(inputData,{"s","O","quick"}))
     {
          return 126;
     }
     if (compare(inputData,{"Apple","O123","three","four","five","six"}))
     {
          return 876;
     }
     if (compare(inputData,{"Apple","iuyt","asde","qwe","asdr"}))
     {
          return 234;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

## Edit1

Can I compare two vector like this:

```
 if(inputData=={"Apple","Orange","three"})
 {
     return 129;
 }
```

Comment: `std::vector` has [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) already. No need to write your own.

Comment: First. pass argument by const reference instead of by copy

Comment: Um, `return vector1 == vector2;`?

Comment: You could make a map of know vector strings to resulting int.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @NathanOliver I updated the question, can I do the comparison in that way?

Comment: @mans You can make an `std::map<std::vector<std::string>>, int>` once and look up in `compare`.

Comment: `inputData == {"Apple","Orange","three"}` is not possible, you need `inputData == std::vector<std::string>{"Apple","Orange","three"}`.

Comment: Are the vectors sorted?

Comment: Is the order of the elements significant? I.e., are {"a","b","c"} and {"a","c","b"} the same? Also, are the fixed strings really fixed?

Comment: I would calculate the hash of your string and then compare with the hashes of the other strings.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking what is the **fastest** way to do this, and you are indicating that you are comparing against a set of fixed and known strings.  I would argue that you would probably have to implement it as a kind of state machine.  Not that this is very beautiful...

```
if (inputData.size() != 3) return 0;
if (inputData[0].size() == 0) return 0;
const char inputData_0_0 = inputData[0][0];
if (inputData_0_0 == 'A') {
   // possibly "Apple" or "A"
   ...
} else if (inputData_0_0 == 's') {
   // possibly "s"
   ...
} else {
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines and looked for some info on fast lexers/scanners e.g. here http://nothings.org/computer/lexing.html

Comment: You can generate the code for these sort of state machines pretty easily however, I would not write it by hand for large numbers of cases. Such a state machine is `O(n)` worst case (match) on the input with no memory allocations so don't believe it can be beaten.

Comment: Can also generate a similar tree structure dynamically at run time.

Answer (score 1):

The weakness of your approach is its linearity. You want a binary search for teh speedz.

By utilising the sortedness of a `map`, the binaryness of finding in one, and the fact that equivalence between `vector`s is already defined for you (no need for that first `compare` function!), you can do this quite easily:

```
std::map<std::vector<std::string>, int> lookup{
   {{"Apple","Orange","three"}, 129},
   {{"A","B","CCC"}, 189},
   // ...
};

int compare(const std::vector<std::string>& inputData)
{
    auto it = lookup.find(inputData);
    if (it != lookup.end())
       return it->second;
    else
       return 0;
}
```

Note also the reference passing for extra teh speedz.

*(I haven't tested this for exact syntax-correctness, but you get the idea.)*

**However!** As always, we need to be context-aware in our designs. This sort of approach is more useful at larger scale. At the moment you only have a few options, so the addition of some dynamic allocation and sorting and all that jazz may actually slow things down. Ultimately, you will want to take my solution, and your solution, and *measure the results* for typical inputs and whatnot.

Once you've done that, if you still need more speed for some reason, consider looking at ways to reduce the dynamic allocations inherent in both the vectors and the strings themselves.

---

To answer your follow-up question: almost; you do need to specify the type:

```
//                   new code is here
//               ||||||||||||||||||||||||
if (inputData == std::vector<std::string>{"Apple","Orange","three"})
{
   return 129;
}
```

As explored above, though, let `std::map::find` do this for you instead. It's better at it.

Comment: I guess key should be int instead of vector in your map

Comment: BTW, with input size (5), it is not the complexity linear vs logarithm search which would be the bottleneck, IMO. [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be interesting.

Comment: @Maddy Why's that? The interface seems to be a lookup _of_ an int _by_ the vector.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, that's a fair point actually. At this scale my whole suggestion is kind of stupid ^_^

Comment: So much teh speedz!

Comment: If you have a lot of common prefixes, be aware that comparing the vectors/strings is individually `O(n)` and such a search must do multiple comparisons. A hash map like `std::unordered_map` avoids that problem partially, but must still do a `O(n)` hash and *at least one* `O(n)` comparison on a hit.

Answer (score 0):

One key to efficiency is eliminating needless allocation.

Thus, it becomes:

```
bool compare(
    std::vector<std::string> const& a,
    std::initializer_list<const char*> b
) noexcept {
    return std::equal(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), end(b));
}
```

Alternatively, make them `static const`, and accept the slight overhead.

As an aside, using C++17 [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) ([look at boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp)), C++20 [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (look for the [Guideline support library (GSL)](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite)) also allows a nicer alternative:

```
bool compare(std::span<std::string> a, std::span<std::string_view> b) noexcept {
    return a == b;
}
```

The other is minimizing the number of comparisons. You can either use hashing, binary search, or manual ordering of comparisons.

Unfortunately, transparent comparators are a C++14 thing, so you cannot use `std::map`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Eliminated that, and even the need to go outside the C++11 standard library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast way to do it where the vectors to compare to are not known in advance, but are reused so can have a little initial run-time overhead, you can build a tree structure similar to the compile time version Dirk Herrmann has. This will run in `O(n)` by just iterating over the input and following a tree.

In the simplest case, you might build a tree for each letter/element. A partial implementation could be:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> Vector;
typedef Vector::const_iterator Iterator;
typedef std::string::const_iterator StrIterator;
struct Node
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> children[256];
    std::unique_ptr<Node> new_str_child;
    int result;
    bool is_result;
};

Node root;
int compare(Iterator vec_it, Iterator vec_end, StrIterator str_it, StrIterator str_end, const Node *node);
int compare(const Vector &input)
{
    return compare(input.begin(), input.end(), input.front().begin(), input.front().end(), &root);
}
int compare(Iterator vec_it, Iterator vec_end, StrIterator str_it, StrIterator str_end, const Node *node)
{
    if (str_it != str_end)
    {
        // Check next character
        auto next_child = node->children[(unsigned char)*str_it].get();
        if (next_child)
            return compare(vec_it, vec_end, str_it + 1, str_end, next_child);
        else return -1; // No string matched
    }
    // At end of input string
    ++vec_it;
    if (vec_it != vec_end)
    {
        auto next_child = node->new_str_child.get();
        if (next_child)
            return compare(vec_it, vec_end, vec_it->begin(), vec_it->end(), next_child);
        else return -1; // Have another string, but not in tree
    }
    // At end of input vector
    if (node->is_result)
        return node->result; // Got a match
    else return -1; // Run out of input, but all possible matches were longer
}
```

Which can also be done without recursion. For use cases like yours you will find most nodes only have a single success value, so you can collapse those into prefix substrings, to use the OP example:

```
"A"
 |-"pple" - new vector - "O" - "range" - new vector - "three" - ret 129
 |                    |- "i" - "uyt"   - new vector - "asde" ... - ret 234
 |                    |- "0" - "123"   - new vector - "three" ... - ret 876
 |- new vector "B" - new vector - "CCC" - ret 189
"s" - new vector "O" - new vector "quick" - ret 126
```

Answer (score -1):

you could make use of std::equal function like below :

```
bool compare(vector<string> input1,vector<string> input2)
{
   if(input1.size() != input2.size()
   {
      return false;
   }

   return std::equal(input1.begin(), input2.end(), input2.begin())
}
```

Comment: This solves the wrong problem; the solution to the problem you're solving is `==` which already exists.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I compare two vector like this

The answer is No, you need compare a vector with another vector, like this:

```
vector<string>data = {"ab", "cd", "ef"};

if(data == vector<string>{"ab", "cd", "efg"})
    cout << "Equal" << endl;
else
    cout << "Not Equal" << endl;
```

> What is the fastest way to do this?

I'm not an expert of asymptotic analysis but:

Using the *relational operator equality* (**==**) you have a shortcut to compare two vectors, first validating the size and, second, each element on them. This way provide a linear execution (**T(n)**, where **n** is the size of vector) which compare each item of the vector, but each string must be compared and, generally, it is another linear comparison (**T(m)**, where m is the size of the string).

Suppose that each string has de same size (*m*) and you have a vector of size *n*, each comparison could have a behavior of *T(nm)*.

So:

- if you want a shortcut to compare two vector you can use the
  *relational operator equality*.
- If you want an program which perform a fast comparison you should look for some algorithm for compare strings.